# "nothing save his haggard look remained of the change that had startled me"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He was dressed in ordinary evening clothes, and ***nothing save his haggard look remained of the change that had startled me***.

The above line appears in *Chapter 2* of "**The Time Machine**" by **H.G. Wells**.
I'm unable to get the meaning of this line. Here, do I equate "save" with "same"? Still my conscience is disturbed as it doubts itself. Please help.

### Edit:

(Pasted from my comment:) I had no idea the "save" was really causing the problem, that is, it had such a usage too. My suggestion for "same" was assuming a typo by the author which I know is very rare. That's why I didn't use a dictionary. I did look for the whole sentence on the Google though.

Comment: It means "except."

Comment: @InanimateBeing I assume whoever downvoted was upset that you didn't look up the meaning of "save" in a dictionary before posting, and include what you saw that you didn't understand. There is no dictionary definition of "save" that would mean anything like "same," as you would have seen if you had used a dictionary.

Comment: @Esther I had no idea the "save" was really causing the problem, that is, it had such a usage too. My suggestion for "same" was assuming a typo by the author which I know is very rare. That's why I didn't use a dictionary. I did look for the whole sentence on the Google though.

Comment: The quote provides enough context  and the source is clearly mentioned which is  more than 70% of the questions posted on ELL.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Save' here means 'except'.

*Nothing save the walls remained after the house burned*

> and nothing except his haggard look remained of the change that had
> startled me

> save
> preposition formal or old-fashioned
>
> but or except for:
>
> *They found all the lost documents save one*

[Save (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/save)

Comment: Alright, got it thank you. Upvoted. Just to confirm though, only his haggard look remained and rest everything had changed. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes - he looked entirely normal except for the haggard look.